# Wordpress Featured image from external link

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

I am inserting data in WordPress from my php script, everything is going smooth but i am facing one big problem to set Featured image from external link. I have almost solve this problem by adding image link to wp_postmeta

[image]

I have added

```
_wp_attached_file with external image link  
_thumbnail_id giving it post id of the link
```

it work fine ... but there a small problem ... image is getting defauld url+external image link

```
http://****.com/wp-content/uploads/http://i.imgur.com/waiBWaV.jpg
```

My Question is how can i remove default link http://****.com/wp-content/uploads/ so only external image link display and i get right image.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use regular expression to trim unusefull part of url.

```
$src = 'http://****.com/wp-content/uploads/http://i.imgur.com/waiBWaV.jpg';
$image =  preg_replace('|.*/(.*?\.[\w]+)|', '\1', $src);
```

Comment: This regular did not works its deleting external url also leaving just waiBWaV.jpg in place  .. can you suggest other regular to just take down url http://****.com/wp-content/uploads/ leaving ttp://i.imgur.com/waiBWaV.jpg in place .... i have used this function  function change_text($in, $out, $text){

$input = array($in);
$change = array($out) ;
$result = @str_replace ($input ,$change, $text);
return $result;
} but i think if i can get exact regular it will be good

Comment: @Harinder, if you sure, that image src would contains http preffix everytime, than this RE should be enough: preg_replace('|.*/(http.*\.[\w]+)|', '\1', $src);

Answer (score 0):

to continue with this subject, is there a way to remove the "default url" (wp-content/uploads/) at the source of the code, not with a regex, and only for image with a alt=external ?